# C++ switch statement not working properly

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

So for a program I'm writing I have a menu the user can enter an integer choice to calculate a few different things. Choice 1-4 are calculations, 5 should call a function to print data from a file to the console, and 6 quits everything. For whatever reason after adding a new case (5) to the switch statement I had, my code has kind of broken. When I enter 5 the program still asks me to enter a weight (which I don't understand at all), after which it will enter an infinite loop, which means it has to have made it into the while loop in my print() function. I don't understand what the hell is going on so I would really appreciate a second set of eyes.

```
int main()
{
srand(time(0));

bool repeat = true;
bool loopFlag = true;
float calories = 0;
string intensity = "";



cout << "Welcome to Carmello's Fitness Center" << endl;

do // main loop
{
    fstream transactionLog;
    transactionLog.open("userfile.txt", std::ios::in |std::ios::out |std::ios::app);

    int idNum;
    menu(idNum); // simply displays the menu

    loopFlag = true;

    int choice = userChoice(choice, loopFlag); // gets the users menu choice
    loopFlag = true; // this resets the loopflag to ensure it can be used again after the last validation

    float weight = userWeight(weight, loopFlag); // gets users weight and converts into kilograms for further calculations
    float weightPoundsCopy = weight;
    weight = weight / 2.2;

    int time = 0;
    float calories = 0;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            int lower = 30, upper = 60;
            int activity = BIKING;
            string description = "riding the stationary bike: ";
            met(weight, loopFlag, activity, lower, upper, description, time, calories, intensity);
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            int lower = 30, upper = 60;
            int activity = RUNNING;
            string description = "running on the treadmill: ";
            met(weight, loopFlag, activity, lower, upper, description, time, calories, intensity);
            break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
            int lower = 15, upper = 30;
            int activity = LIFTING;
            string description = "lifting weights: ";
            met(weight, loopFlag, activity, lower, upper, description, time, calories, intensity);
            break;
        }
    case 4:
        {
            int lower = 60, upper = 90;
            int activity = YOGA;
            string description = "doing Hatha Yoga: ";
            met(weight, loopFlag, activity, lower, upper, description, time, calories, intensity);
            break;
        }
    case 5:
        {
            cout << "5 CHOSEN";
            print (transactionLog);
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(5) << idNum << endl;
    cout << choice << endl;
    cout << time << endl;
    cout << weightPoundsCopy << endl;
    cout << calories << endl;
    cout << intensity << endl;

    outputFunction(transactionLog, idNum, choice, time, weightPoundsCopy, calories, intensity);
    transactionLog.close();
}
while (repeat);
}
```

Here are what seem to be the most relevant functions

```
int userChoice (int choice, bool loopFlag)
{
    do // loop to validate user's activity (choice) input
    {
        cin >> choice;
        if (cin.fail() || choice > 6 || choice < 1)
        {
            cout << "\nInvalid choice. Please choose from option 1 through 6." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        }
        else if (choice == 6)
        {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // exits program if user chooses to
        }
        else
        {
            loopFlag = false;
        }
    }
    while (loopFlag); // loop will continue until input meets correct conditions and thus sets loopflag to false

    return choice;
}
```

and

```
float userWeight(float weightPounds, bool loopFlag)
{
    do // this do-while loop validates weight input
        {
        cout << "\nPlease enter your weight in pounds: " << endl;
        cin >> weightPounds;

        if (cin.fail() || weightPounds <= 0 || weightPounds >= 1000)
        {
            cout << "\nInvalid weight entry!" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        }
        else
        {
            loopFlag = false;
        }
    }
    while (loopFlag);

    return weightPounds;
}
```

and

```
void print(fstream &transactionLog)
{
    // reset everything and go to the beginning of the file
transactionLog.clear();
transactionLog.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
// start the streaming >>
if (enterPassword)
{
    while(!transactionLog.eof())
    {
        cout << setw(20) << left << "UserID" << "Activity" << "Mins" << "Weight"
             << "Calories" << "Intensity" << "Time Stamp" << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "SECURITY BREACH" << endl;
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to evaluate what's going on?

Comment: Please see [mcve] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: I don't understand why you reset the loopFlag variable after calling your userChoice function because this variable is not passed by reference

Comment: @Johnmph The program has been modified a lot recently so that's a leftover from an older version. Don't think it's the issue though as it's been like that since I started.

Comment: This is not a free debugging service. Please use a debugger to narrow down on the part that is not working properly and post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you still can't figure it out. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: @FeiXiang No idea how to do that. Just asking for help

Comment: Look at the page I linked to. Debugging is not something I can teach you in a StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works as it been written. You has beed asked user made his choice by calling "userChoice" function and in anyway after that you has beed asked a user weight by calling "userWeight" function. Only after that you has been parsed user input in a switch case.

If you want that your program didn't asked user weight you should written somethin like that:

```
if (userInput < 5)
{
    weight = userWeight(weight, loopFlag);
    float weightPoundsCopy = weight;
    weight = weight / 2.2;
}
```